# Object shown in different places between mods

Tags: objects, 3d-view

[image: It's normal in object mode but in edit mode this is what happens to floor object.]

It's normal in object mode but in edit mode this is what happens to floor object.

---

[image]

This is object mode view.
.....

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvGCM.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvGCM.jpg) I got it guys midlevel should be 0

Answer (score 1):

You have a *Displace* modifier, it changes the position of the vertices when you're in *Object* mode, and the vertices come back to their original position when you're in *Edit* mode. Check your *Displace* modifier settings if you want the vertices to stay at about the same Z position.